NextJS Image Component - Title
I am trying to set the Image title with the NextJS Image component but looks like it doesnt take the attribtute. Any hack on how to get it to work?
<Image
            src={logoChatGPT}
            alt="ChatGPT"
            title="ChatGPT"
            width={24}
            height={24}
            className='ml-2'
          />


In NextJS 14 the title attribute appears to be added in the rendered HTML

@Balaji u mean the alt text will also be added as the title?

No, I mean to say that the title="ChatGPT" is present in the HTML as expected.

@Balaji its not showing up

you need to expand your question as the problem does not come from the code snippet you posted, a reproduction on codesandbox would be a big plus, I'm also not aware of a bug in next/image so the code you are showing should produce the desired result
